# Counting hits from a certain browser

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?PHP
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","userinfo");
       // Check connection
       if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

if ($result) {
    $Chromerows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_stats WHERE Browser = 'Chrome'"));
    $Firefoxrows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM tbl_stats WHERE Browser = 'Firefox'"));
    echo 'Chrome' . " : " . $Chromerows . "   |   ". 'Firefox' . " : ". $Firefoxrows;
}


}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

So basically i have a database that stores when a user views from a certain browser, operating system and their ip.

I need to display on a page a hits counter showing the amount of hits from that browser, I've tried to follow tutorials and look up how to do this but have failed so far, i dunno if this is any close.

Comment: so what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

For getting which browser is used by the users you can use : `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and store into your database. [For more information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

Why after connecting to database you exeucting a query : `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);` and looping `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){}` remove that there is no need.

Your code contains multiple errors please add this code

```
       $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","userinfo");
       // Check connection
       if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       }
       else
       {

           $Chromerows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_stats WHERE Browser = 'Chrome'"));

           $Firefoxrows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_stats WHERE Browser = 'Firefox'"));

           echo 'Chrome' . " : " . $Chromerows . "   |   ". 'Firefox' . " : ". $Firefoxrows;   

       }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, had to change the $connection next to the mysqli_query to $con to work with mine but now it works perfectly!

Comment: @user3590646 if you got the solution please mark this answer as accepeted

Answer (score 0):

To detect which browser someone is using, you can use get_browser();

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 0):

First of all: There is no possible way to do this.

**Solution 1**

One solution is like you did, by saving the user agent and ip.

But why does this not work correctly?

1. There are dynamic ip-addresses: These are IPs that change after a time. A user can get multiple IPs.
2. Internal networks: In schools, companies, ... are a lot of people on the same IP address. If they use the same Operating System and browser (believe me, that happens a lot!), they will act as the same browser, while it's a complete other user.

**Solution 2**

Another and better way is to create a cookie for the user when he's visiting your website for the first time and to save the information with that cookie.

The only problem that you have then is that users can delete cookies, but the most of them don't do that. Ever. So I think this is the most suitable solution. You can then just count the items in your database with the id that is stored in that cookie.

**FYI: Use ALWAYS a random string as identification. Users can change their cookies and you don't want them to get in another "session". You can check then if their is a cookie that don't exists in your database, it's false and create another.**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these lines are unnecessary unless you didn't show us the full code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

if ($result) {
```

Your script could look like this (you can do it with one query):

```
<?PHP
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","userinfo");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } else {
    $get_rows = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`, `Browser` FROM tbl_stats GROUP BY `Browser` HAVING `Browser` IN('Chrome', 'Firefox') ORDER BY `Browser` ASC");
    $get_chrome = mysqli_fetch_array($get_rows);
    $get_firefox = mysqli_fetch_array($get_rows);
    echo 'Chrome' . " : " . $get_chrome['count'] . "   |   ". 'Firefox' . " : ". $get_firefox['count'];
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query instead to count the browser usage:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `Browser`, COUNT(*) as `Usage` FROM `tbl_stats` GROUP BY `Browser`");
```

Now you can echo the results like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $result)) {
    echo "Browser: " . $row['Browser'] . " Usage: " . $row['Usage'];
}
```

Comment: It counts how many times the same value is used in the 'Browser' column. The second part shows you the amount for every value, so I think it answers the question.

Comment: there are other errors in op code please see the code properly

Comment: Sorry, where you have fixed it? I am not able to see any new edit

Comment: OP does not have errors in sql query there is an error after connecting to the database

Comment: I forgot to add the '$con' parameter in the 'mysqli_query'. "I need to display on a page a hits counter showing the amount of hits from that browser", the while-loop i posted does the trick.

Comment: let it be you will not understand